# Custom line number with listings

Tags: listings

I would like to know if it is possible to set custom line numbers in conjunction with the listings package. Please find below a MWE. I'd just like the last line (numbered 8) to appear as e.g. number 500. If not with listings, would you have any other suggestion ?

Thanks and best regards

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily, frame=single, columns=fullflexible, keepspaces=true, numbers=left,  stepnumber=1]
Record Length,2.500000e+03,,  -0.001250000000,  -0.76000,
Sample Interval,1.000000e-06,,  -0.001249000000,  -0.74000,
,,,-00.001225000000,  -0.64000,
,,,-00.001224000000,  -0.62000,

... 

,,,00.001249000000,   0.78000,
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=8 5000\else\arabic{lstnumber}\fi}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily, frame=single,
columns=fullflexible, keepspaces=true, numbers=left,  stepnumber=1]
Record Length,2.500000e+03,,  -0.001250000000,  -0.76000,
Sample Interval,1.000000e-06,,  -0.001249000000,  -0.74000,
,,,-00.001225000000,  -0.64000,
,,,-00.001224000000,  -0.62000,

... 

,,,00.001249000000,   0.78000,
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear David, thank you very much. That was what I was looking for !

Comment: BTW, although the original question is correctly solved, and just for my curiosity... Would it be possible, to set at a specific line, a custom number from which all remaining following lines are renumbered accordingly  ?

Comment: @Sergio yes for example you could change the `\if` to say `\ifnum\value{lstnumber}>7\relax \the\numexpr 5008-\value{lstnumber}\relax\else\arabic{lstmumber}\fi` (probably:-)